# Can't drop a table with bindParam using PDO and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For example this works fine:

```
$dropTable = $dbConnection->prepare('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS announcements');
$dropTable->execute();

$createTable = $dbConnection->prepare('CREATE TABLE announcements(
            id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            announcements TEXT NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (id))');
$createTable->execute();
```

But this fails:

```
$dropTable = $dbConnection->prepare('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS :tableToDrop');
$dropTable->bindParam(':tableToDrop', $_GET['table']);
$dropTable->execute();

$createTable = $dbConnection->prepare('CREATE TABLE announcements(
        id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            announcements TEXT NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (id))');
$createTable->execute();
```

With Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:   
  Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;   
  check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right  
  syntax to use near '?' at line 1' in xxxx/createTables.php:9  
Stack trace: #0 xxxxx/createTables.php(9):   
  PDO->prepare('DROP TABLE IF E...') #1 {main} thrown in xxxx/createTables.php on line 9
```

I'm sure it's something trivial, but I've been going at it for hours. Cheers.

Edit: Turns out you can't [bindParam with a table name](http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/4602-dynamic-tablename-with-pdo-prepare/).Is there anyway to do a secure prepared statement with a dynamic table name?

Comment: Is `$_GET['table']` set with a value?

Comment: There's only a handful of places where you can use a placeholder, the table name is not one of them. I don't have a link to reference, that's why it's just a comment.

Comment: @Maerlyn Oh, that may be right. I think I saw reference to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe way (and u should use that, event if what u wrote could work):

```
$t=array('t1'=>'t1','t2'=>'t2'....'tn'=>'tn');

$sql = "drop table {$t[$_GET['table']]} ..."
```

Comment: Cheers mate, never would have thought of that.